# How could we locate lambda position at the source file by there `getClass().getName()`?

Tags: java, jvm

We have some log online, they looks like `com.xxx.yyy.SomeClass$$Lambda$12345/7654321@qwert`.
Those logs point to some lambda functions (functional interface) like `Runnable runnable = () -> {}`, however the `SomeClass` have lots of lambda functions, so need to find the specific line of them at the source file in order to locate the wrong.

By the way, what we've figured out is that all the log of those lambda functions looks `$package.$ClassName$$Lambda$index/$number@hashCode`, and the same lambda have the same `$index/$number` before the class recompiled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is impossible. The class is generated at runtime and does not reflect the code location that triggered the class generation. The observed index number reflects the order of the class generation, not the appearance of the lambda expression in the code.

As long as the program’s behavior does not change, it may look as if there was a stable mapping between this number and the code location, but we can easily disprove this by creating a program that deliberately changes its behavior:

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class LambdaClassGeneration {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if(args.length == 0) {
            runMyself();
            return;
        }

        boolean even = args[0].equals("even");

        for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++, even = !even) {
            Runnable r;
            StackTraceElement e;
            if(even) {
                r = () -> System.out.println("even");
                e = new Exception().getStackTrace()[0];
            }
            else {
                r = () -> System.out.println("odd");
                e = new Exception().getStackTrace()[0];
            }
            r.run();
            System.out.println("created at "+e);
            System.out.println(r.getClass());
        }
    }

    private static void runMyself() {
        String[] cmd = {
            Paths.get(System.getProperty("java.home"), "bin", "java").toString(),
            "-cp", System.getProperty("java.class.path"),
            MethodHandles.lookup().lookupClass().getName(),
            "arg"
        };
        ProcessBuilder p = new ProcessBuilder().inheritIO();

        for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++) try {
            System.out.println("Run " + i);
            cmd[cmd.length-1] = i%2 == 0? "even": "odd";
            p.command(cmd).start().waitFor();
            System.out.println();
        }
        catch(IOException | InterruptedException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

This program runs itself twice with different parameters, `"even"` and `"odd"`, to exhibit different behavior, affecting the order in which the lambda expressions are evaluated to objects of a `Runnable` implementation at runtime.

It prints something like:

```
Run 0
even
created at LambdaClassGeneration.main(LambdaClassGeneration.java:20)
class LambdaClassGeneration$$Lambda$1/0x0000000800b90840
odd
created at LambdaClassGeneration.main(LambdaClassGeneration.java:24)
class LambdaClassGeneration$$Lambda$2/0x0000000800b91440

Run 1
odd
created at LambdaClassGeneration.main(LambdaClassGeneration.java:24)
class LambdaClassGeneration$$Lambda$1/0x0000000800b90840
even
created at LambdaClassGeneration.main(LambdaClassGeneration.java:20)
class LambdaClassGeneration$$Lambda$2/0x0000000800b91440
```

Clearly showing that the first generated class gets index one and the second generated class gets index two and there’s nothing in the class name hinting at whether we are looking at the “even” or “odd” runnable.